# Event fired only once when watching a directory

Tags: java, nio

Using the java.nio watching service, I try to watch a directory and all of its subdirectories:

```
Files.walkFileTree(projectPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
   @Override
   public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);
        watched.put(key, new WatchableDirectory(dir, projectPath));
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

Then I wait for events:

```
executor.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                WatchKey key;
                while ((key = watcher.take()) != null) {
                    List<WatchEvent<?>> events = key.pollEvents();
                    WatchableDirectory watchableDirectory = watched.get(key);
                    for (WatchEvent<?> event : events) {
                         ....
                    }
             }
          ....
         }
    }
```

(`watched` is a `Map` that holds mappings from a key to metadata about the directory)

However, only the first event for a given directory is fired. Whenever I change another file in a directory, where a file has already been changed, nothing happens (I validate that by both putting a breakpoint and expecting the logic in the for-loop to take place).

However, if I modify a file in another directory, then everything works (again, only the first time).

No exceptions are thrown (there is a catch clause for `java.lang.Exception`), and the loop obviously continues to run.

I thought that probably once consumed, the directory might be deregistered. So I added a line to re-register it after its file is being handled. No effect.

Windows 7, Java 7.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Don't forget to call

```
key.reset();
```

after you are done using it in your `while` loop.

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchKey.html#reset%28%29) state

> Otherwise if there are pending events for the object then this watch
>   key is immediately re-queued to the watch service. If there are no
>   pending events then the watch key is put into the ready state and will
>   remain in that state until an event is detected or the watch key is
>   cancelled.

and

> Watch keys are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads. Where
>   there are several threads retrieving signalled keys from a watch
>   service then care should be taken to ensure that the reset method is
>   only invoked after the events for the object have been processed. This
>   ensures that one thread is processing the events for an object at any
>   time.

So if you don't reset, it's as if your watch is disabled.

`WatchKey#reset()` returns a boolean value for if it is valid or not. Handle that case as explained in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

[Marko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180547/event-fired-only-once-when-watching-a-directory/20180688?noredirect=1#comment30085836_20180688) emphasises:

> **After the events for the key have been processed, you need to put the
>   key back into a ready state by invoking reset. If this method returns
>   false, the key is no longer valid and the loop can exit. This step is
>   very important. If you fail to invoke reset, this key will not receive
>   any further events.**

Comment: This quote is the most poignant: "This step is very **important**. If you fail to invoke reset, this key will not receive any further events."